# Plotting ROC curve in python using trapezoidal rule without any library (numpy, sklearn etc.)

Tags: python, roc, auc

I faced this problem where I was asked to calculate area under curve from 2 arrays X & Y in python. I searched over internet and couldn't find any relevant solution / approach.

Please guide how to proceed to solve this problem.

Comment: If you cannot use any special libraries (there is a method exactly for this purpose in numpy - trapz), then your problem becomes entirely mathematical and is out of scope of Stack Overflow. Once you work out the formula, you can write some code (it won't be complex) and come back if you have any problems with it.

Comment: To be frank I encountered this problem in a coding interview platform. I was unable to resolve the problem because of absence of numpy and sklearn. I did try creating a trapezoidal rule function but did not help.